# Creating a string array from a line-separated text file

Tags: c

I have been supplied a txt file of words where there is only one word per line. I have been asked to read it into a string array where each element of the array is a line from this txt file. I have attempted a few solutions with fgets but haven't had much luck so far, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated?

One of the solutions I tried was something along the lines of:

```
char array[45440][20];
char copyToArray = fgets(array[r][20], 100000, inputFile);
for (int r = 0; r < fileLength; r++) {
    if(copyToArray != NULL) {
        strcpy(array[r][20], copyToArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: A loop that calls `fgets()` is the way to go. What problem are you having? Make sure you make a copy of the line for each element of the array, don't use the same string repeatedly.

Comment: If you want more help, you need to post your code so we can show you where you went wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: One of the solutions I tried was something along the lines of:

char copyToArray = fgets(array[r][20], 100000, inputFile);
for (int r = 0; r < fileLength; r++) {
  if(copyToArray != NULL) {
   strcpy(array[r][20], copyToArray);
  }
 }

Comment: Why `array[r][20]` instead of `array[r]`? How is `array` declared?

Comment: Put your code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: `int r = 0; while(fgets(array[r], sizeof(*array), inputFile)) ++r;`

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the expected number of strings and the maximum word length, use this:

```
char array[45440][20];
int n;
for (n = 0; n < 45440; n++) {
    if (scanf("%19[^\n]", array[n]) != 1)
        break;
    scanf("%*[^\n]);  /* skip the rest of the line if any */
    scanf("%*c);      /* skip the newline if any */
}
```

Or this simpler alternative:

```
char array[45440][20];
int n, c, i;
for (n = 0; n < 45440; n++) {
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n';) {
        if (i < 19)
            array[n][i++] = '\0';
    }
    array[n][i] = '\0';
    if (c == EOF)
        break;
}
```